Does this sum-of-digits and prime-factorization-related sequence go on forever? Can it be proved?
Recently I've been playing with the notion of a function that sums all the numbers in a prime factorization -- not just the primes, but the exponents as well, using $1$ as an exponent when necessary. For example, $12 = 2^2 \cdot 3^1$, therefore $\text{pfs}(12) = 2 + 2 + 3 + 1 = 8.$ Similarly, $\text{pfs}(81) = 3 + 4 = 7$ and $\text{pfs}(30) = 2 + 1 + 3 + 1 + 5 + 1 = 13$. Patterns immediately emerge, for example, $\text{pfs}(p) = p + 1$ for all primes $p$, $4$ is the only number for which $\text{pfs}(x) = x$, etc. When iterating the function, we find the loops $4 \to 4$ and $5 \to 6 \to 7 \to 8 \to 5$. You can iterate the function starting with other numbers as well, but, except for $2$ and $3$, they all seem to lead to the latter loop. As an example, $61 \to 62 \to 35 \to 14 \to 11 \to 12 \to 8 \to 5...$

Do all numbers greater than $4$ end up in the $5 \to 6 \to 7 \to 8 \to 5$ loop? How would you prove this?

Soon after formulating this idea, I realized that $\text{pfs}(36) = 2 + 2 + 3 + 2 = 9$, which is the sum of the digits of $36$. Further pen-and-paper experimentation demonstrated that several other numbers have this property -- that is, the property that $\text{pfs}(x)$ equals the sum of the digits of $x$ -- such as $4, 25, 54, 125,$ etc. Writing a program in Python made it clear that there are many more of these numbers; here are the ones below $100,000$:
$$4, 25, 36, 54, 125, 192, 289 ,297, 343, 392, 448, 676, 756, 1089, 1536, 1764, 1936, 2646, 2888, 3872, 4802, 4860, 6174, 6250, 6776, 6860, 7290, 7488, 7680, 8750, 8775, 9408, 9747, 10648, 14739, 15309, 16848, 18432, 18865, 21296, 22869, 25725, 29988, 33750, 33957, 34375, 35721, 37268, 37908, 39936, 41472, 46585, 48672, 56250, 56862, 56875, 57344, 59488, 62208, 65219, 66825, 68782, 69938, 73695, 75264, 83853, 85536, 93312...$$
My primary question:

Is it possible to prove that these numbers go on forever? What about in other bases?

In addition:

Does this sequence have any patterns? In density (does the numbers get scarcer as they get larger)? In the ones digit? In the prime factorizations?


Does this sequence have any usefulness whatsoever? Is it related to any other useful sequences?

Thanks for your help! (Happy to clarify if anything was unclear.)

Interestingly, this is not in OEIS.

Yes, I apologise, "precisely" is not quite correct, still you can try to prove the relation $\text{pfs}(n) \leq n+1$ with strong induction, and try to prove the "precisely" part(when prime) for large enough $n$.

I count about eight questions here. The system is designed for questions that ask one question, not for questions that ask eight questions.

@JohnOmielan Thanks for pointing that out! That should be fixed now -- what I meant to say was that the loop is $4 \to 4$, and $2$ and $3$ are the only numbers that end in that loop (besides $4$, of course).

@GerryMyerson If it makes more sense for this system, you can think about only my main question, that is, "Do the numbers go on forever and how do you prove that?"

What makes more sense is for you to delete most of the question, and just leave one focussed question for users to work on.

I think proving your first observation "That all numbers greater than $4$ end up in $5 \to 6 \to 7 \to 8 \to 5$ loop." is more approachable, than your second question about the sum of digits and $\text{pfs}$.
I will first prove that $\text{pfs}(n)\leq n+1$ and then that for composite numbers $n > 10: \text{pfs}(n) <n-1$.
So first let us observe, that $\text{pfs}(n) \leq n+1$ holds for all prime numbers, and all numbers $2\dots8$. Let's suppose now, that this statement holds for all $k \leq n$ and we wish to prove it for $k=n+1$. Let us separate three cases:

If $n+1$ is prime, then obivously $\text{pfs}(n+1) \leq n+2$
If $n+1 = q^k$, for some prime $q$ and $k \geq 2$, then $\text{pfs}(q^k) = 1 + \text{pfs}(q^{k-1}) \overbrace{\leq}^{\text{I.H.}} 2 + q^{k-1}$. Also
$q^{k-1} \leq q^k-1$ for all primes $q$ and $k \geq2$, so $$\text{pfs}(n+1) 
= \text{pfs}(q^k) \leq2+q^{k-1} \leq q^k + 1 = n+2.$$
If $n+1$ is composite(but not a power of a prime), then $n+1=ab$ for $a,b \geq 2$ coprime. Now, the function $x+\frac{n+1}{x}$ is decreasing on $x \in [2,\sqrt{n+1}]$, so $a+b \leq 2+\frac{n+1}{2}$, which for $n \geq 5$ implies that $a+b\leq2+\frac{n+1}{2} \leq n$. Adding 2 to all sides gives $a+b+2 \leq n+2$, and finally:
$$\text{pfs}(n+1) = \text{pfs}(ab) = \text{pfs(a)} + \text{pfs}(b) \underbrace{\leq}_{\text{I.H.}} a+b+2\leq n+2.$$

Now let's focus on composite numbers $n > 10$.

If $n=q^k$, for some prime $q$ and $k \geq 2$, then $\text{pfs}(q^k) = 1+\text{pfs}(q^{k-1}) \leq 2+q^{k-1}$, and $2+q^{k-1} < q^k-1$(alternativly $q^{k-1}(1-q) < -3$) holds for all $q\geq 3$ and $q=2,k\geq3$, so if $n > 10$ then $$\text{pfs}(n) = 1+\text{pfs}(p^{k-1}) \leq 2+q^{k-1}< q^k-1 = n-1.$$
If $n = ab$, for some $a,b \geq 2$ coprime, then similarly as before $a+b \leq 2+\frac{n}{2}$, so $a+b+2 \leq 4+\frac{n}{2}$, and $4+\frac{n}{2} < n-1$ hold for $n > 10$, so $$\text{pfs}(n) = \text{pfs}(a) + \text{pfs}(b) \leq a+b+2 \leq 4+\frac{n}{2} < n-1.$$

If we start at a number $n > 10$ and consecutively apply $\text{pfs}$, we either get:

$n \to n+1 \to m < n$, if $n$ is prime
$n \to m < n$, if $n$ is composite

In both cases we get to a number smaller than what we started with, so after iterating, we eventually reach a number $n_0 \leq 10$, and all numbers $\leq 10$ lead to the cycle $5 \to 6 \to 7 \to 8 \to 5$ or $4 \to 4$. If $\text{pfs}(n) = 4$, then $n$ must be $3$ or $4$, and if $\text{pfs}(n) = 3$ then $n$ must be $2$, so no other number than $2,3,4$ reach the $4 \to 4$ cycle.
